# What is the correct way to replace a set of records using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Our app receives a list of records that are to replace an existing set of records. Each record has a primary key based on a sequence, and a unique constraint on another field, which is a foreign key (i.e an alternate key) on something else.

It goes something like this:

```
   for each old record
      delete the old record
   next

   for each new record
      insert new record
   next
```

The problem is that Hibernate is running the inserts before the delete and consequently raising a unique constraint violation. The new records have the same alternate key as the old ones.

If I remove the unique constraint it works fine.

What is the correct way to do something like this?

Comment: Did you try flushing the EntityManager after the deletion occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1. you could use merge, this will "replace" the record in database depending on you implementation;
2. you could try to flush all modifications between both fors.

Comment: Actually, although flushing does resolve the problem I've decided to do things properly and merge the changed records. So thanks for both of your suggestions!